# Plotting the bin counts in a specific region of 2D heatmap?

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a bar chart of the counts in a specific region of a heatmap in python. I have successfully coded the heatmap and also figured out how to draw boundaries around specific regions. However, I am stuck when it comes to plotting a bar chart of the counts in a specific region. The heatmap is a 2D histogram. I want to convert it to a 1D histogram for my selected region. The x-axis will be the same as x-axis in the heatmap. The y-axis should be the counts (represented by intensity of colors in heatmap).

```
df = pd.read_csv('adc_tdc_7_disk26.txt', sep=',', header=None)

x, y = df[0].to_numpy(),df[1].to_numpy()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
counts, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=1000)
counts = counts.T 
im = ax.imshow(counts,cmap='magma_r',origin='lower',norm=LogNorm())
fig.colorbar(im)
click_points = []

def onselect(event):
    click_points.append((event.xdata,event.ydata))
# 20 clicks draws a boundary
    if len(click_points) >= 20:
        polygon_verts = click_points

        polygon_patch = plt.Polygon(polygon_verts,facecolor='none',edgecolor='r')


        ax.add_patch(polygon_patch)

        fig.canvas.draw()

        hist_points(polygon_patch,counts,xedges,yedges)
        click_points.clear()

def hist_points(polygon_patch,counts,xedges,yedges):
# checking for indices of points that lie inside this selected region.
    selected_indices = np.nonzero(polygon_patch.contains_points(np.column_stack((x,y))))
```

So far this is what I have. I can select the region that I want and I can also check which points lie inside the selected region. However, I am not sure how do I extract the counts in that selected region. Any help would be highly appreciated!

The heatmap without the boundary looks something like this:
[image: Heatmap without boundaries]

When I add the boundaries:
[image: With boundaries]

Comment: You said you can extract the selected region and determine the points in it, but then you say you can't find the values of those points. I don't quite see how both can be true at the same time. Could you please explain what you mean in detail, preferably with relevant code?

Comment: You appear to have a function that return a mask (if you take out `nonzero`). You can get the elements you want with `counts[mask]`. The bounds are `counts[mask].min()` and `counts[mask].max()`. Does that help, or are you asking for something else?

Comment: What I mean is that I can see which points (x,y) lie inside the region but what I am really after is the variable counts in that selected region (see code). How do I extract the value of counts in that specific region?

Comment: Use the result of `nonzero`, or its input (which is a mask), on the image array.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I didn't understand this.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The heatmap is a 2D histogram. I want to convert it to a 1D histogram for my selected region. The x-axis will be the same as x-axis in the heatmap. The y-axis should be the counts (represented by intensity of colors in heatmap).

Comment: Gotcha. I misunderstood the first part of the question. Will answer momentarily.

Comment: I think you should [edit] your question to explain what your intended output is a bit better. I did not understand how you meant to construct the bar graph otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have an image `counts`, and a way of extracting some region of it as a mask. In this case, that way appears to be the line `polygon_patch.contains_points(np.column_stack((x,y)))`. I will refer to the result of that call as `mask`.

`np.nonzero(mask)` retrieves a pair of indices, in this case the `y` and `x` coordinates of the masked values. There are a couple of ways you can group the data by the x-coordinate. Using pure numpy, first sort the data and the indices:

```
y, x = np.nonzero(mask)
region_counts = counts[y, x]
idx = x.argsort()
x = x[idx]
region_counts = region_counts[idx]
```

Now you can use an idiom with `np.add.reduceat` to compute the count for each x-bin:

```
splits = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(x)) + 1]
counts_1d = np.add.reduceat(region_counts, splits)
```

The indices `splits` are where the sorted `x` values change. `x[splits]` gives you the x-values, taken from the first element in each bin.

You can now plot the result with something like

```
plt.bar(x[splits], counts_1d)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, np.nonzero(mask) returns a 1D array of indices and assigning two values to it gives errors. Actually I am not sure why contains_points() only returns a 1D boolean array. Do I need to feed in a meshgrid for it to return a 2D boolean array?

Comment: @cr_007. What is the shape of the array? You may be able to just do `mask.reshape(count.shape)`

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work because the size of count is 1000x1000 while the mask array is size is 335352 (1D array)

Comment: @cr_007 In that case you will have to show your inputs and imports, or figure out how to transform whatever your version of `mask` is into mine. I can't guess what your data looks like, or what packages you are using.